# PL SQL - Rename data type attribute on update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**How can I rename a data type attribute while updating him ?**

*For example, imagine I have a type like this :*

> data_type.with.a.lot.of.sub.attributes

```
UPDATE table t
SET t.data_type.with.a.lot.of.sub.attributes = 5 * t.data_type.with.a.lot.of.sub.attributes;
```

I looking for a solution which provide something like this :

```
UPDATE table t
SET (t.data_type.with.a.lot.of.sub.attributes AS attr) = 5 * attr;
```

**Example :**

```
...

CREATE TYPE data_type3 AS OBJECT (
    lot data_type4;
);

CREATE TYPE data_type2 AS OBJECT (
    a data_type3;
);

CREATE TYPE data_type AS OBJECT (
    with data_type2;
);
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful.  As is, I'm not understanding how you would set multiple columns/attributes to a single value.

Comment: It's only theoretical, I'm not in such a situation but the question crossed my mind. I added some type definitions that could lead to this situation.